# Two domains one ssl

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, domain

We have a production rails app being hosted on heroku at http://abc123.com. We also have a wordpress blog hosted on bluehost at http://abc123blog.com. We use Rack::ReverseProxy to make it look as if wordpress is being served from http:://abc123.com/blog.

This breaks down because we would like to host everything using ssl certs. I was wondering if there is anyway we cold put both domains under one ssl cert or possibly have separate certs for each site and make then 'play nicely'?

Comment: Are users ever directly accessing the blog domain?  If they're being reverse proxied to it, there's no reason you'd need to have valid SSL for it.

Comment: @ShaneMadden could you go more in to that? How can a domain with ssl safely serve content from a domain without one?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to clarify what you're trying to achieve.

With a reverse proxy, the user connects to only the `abc123.com` server.  When they request something within `/blog`, the `abc123.com` server makes a connection to the `abc123blog.com` server, makes a request, gets a response, then feeds that response back to the user.

- If you're trying to encrypt the user's access to `abc123.com`, then get it a certificate, and you're done.
- If you're *also* trying to encrypt the `abc123.com` connection to the `abc123blog.com` server, you will need a second SSL cert, but you don't need to buy one - a self-signed cert trusted by the `abc123.com` server would be sufficient.
- If users actually make requests to `abc123blog.com` instead of accessing all resources via the reverse-proxied `abc123.com/blog` path, then you aren't reverse proxying all the access to the blog.  You need valid, signed SSL certificates on both domains.

Comment: Can you expand on creating a self-signed cert that will be trusted by abc123.com

Comment: @DanielMcGraw What OS are your servers on?  They should have a self-signed cert by default.

Comment: I'm sure both are some sort of flavor of linux. The specifics beyond that I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, before we go too far down that road - what you're trying to solve for is getting the "backend" reverse proxy traffic, from the `abc123.com` server to the `abc123blog.com` server, encrypted - correct?